# Add badge for android with codenameone

Tags: codenameone

We tried more time to find badges with android using codename one, but I found some comments in stackoverflow is only working on IOS and not working on android, if true so when will it become available on android?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we created the badge code Android didn't support that UI paradigm. Arguably it still doesn't but some vendors include that functionality with a special API.

Currently the main thing holding this back is that no one asked for it or implemented it. First of all I suggest filing an RFE which will give you a way to track the schedule for adding this. You can add an RFE on http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

You can also just implement this yourself and submit a pull request as explained in this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

This should be relatively easy although you will need to be careful with using the right API level options and might need to use reflection to avoid SDK dependencies which we don't want.

Other than that it's just a matter of interest if we need to implement it. If you have an enterprise account then make sure to let us know through the account of your interest in this feature. We also take pro account requests more seriously when assigning a feature.